# Making dropped clone element draggable again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a few table-blocks, and whole table with workout cells .
When dragging I use helper to clone .table-block and later I append it to .workout-cell on drop. When dropped to .workout cell I can't move it anymore. I want to make it draggable again within the table, and be able to move it. How to do this?

Here is code:

```
$( ".table-block" ).draggable({     
  helper : "clone", 
});

$(".workout-cell").droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
    $(this).append(element);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.draggable` on the cloned element:

```
$(".workout-cell").droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
    $(this).append(element);
    $(element).draggable({helper: 'clone'});
  }
});
```

Comment: FYI, but this needs to be done before appending the clone to the dom. For example: `clone.droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var element=$(ui.draggable).clone();
    $(this).append(element);
    $(element).draggable({helper: 'clone'});
  }
});
clone.appendTo('body')`